# PHP PDO Not Inserting to Database

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert, pdo

im working on PDO's, i've been trying  on this for many hours but still couldn't succeded to insert the inputs into the database. I dont get any errors, hence i get my $err -> succeded message. But no chance on inserting to database...

Would be glad if you can help.

note: about the user id, im getting the id from another table, column userid, and trying to insert it to another table, "params_user_id" column.

Here is my code :

```
if(isset($_POST["create"])) {
try{

$param1 = cleanInput($_POST["param1"]);
$param2 = cleanInput($_POST["param2"]);
$param3 = cleanInput($_POST["param3"]);
$param4 = cleanInput($_POST["param4"]);
$param5id = cleanInput($_POST["param5id"]);
$param6id = cleanInput($_POST["param6id"]);
$param7 = cleanInput($_POST["param7"]);
$param8id = cleanInput($_POST["param8id"]);
$param9 = cleanInput($_POST["param9"]);
$param10 = cleanInput($_POST["param10"]);
$param11 = cleanInput($_POST["param11"]);
$param12 = cleanInput($_POST["param12"]);
$param13 = cleanInput($_POST["param13"]);
$param14 = cleanInput($_POST["param14"]);
$param15 = cleanInput($_POST["param15"]);
$param16 = cleanInput($_POST["param16"]);
$param17 = cleanInput($_POST["param17"]);
$param18 = cleanInput($_POST["param18"]);
$param19 = cleanInput($_POST["param19"]);
$param20 = cleanInput($_POST["param20"]);
$param21 = cleanInput($_POST["param21"]);
$userid = $_SESSION[':userid'];
$datenow = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');


$create_params_query = "INSERT INTO `params`(`datenow`, `param1`, `param2`, `param3`, `param4`, `param5id`, `param6id`, `param7`, `param8id`, `param9`, `param10`, `param11`, `param12`, `param13`, `param14`, `param15`, `param16`, `param17`, `param18`, `param19`, `param20`, `param21`,`params_user_id`) VALUE(:datenow, :param1, :param2, :param3, :param4, :param5id, :param6id, :param7, :param8id, :param9, :param10, :param11, :param12, :param13, :param14, :param15, :param16, :param17, :param18, :param19, :param20, :param21, :userid)";

$create_params_do = $db->prepare($create_params_query);
$create_params_do -> bindParam(':datenow', $datenow, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$create_params_do -> bindParam(':param1', $param1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$create_params_do -> bindParam(':param2', $param2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$create_params_do -> bindParam(':param3', $param3, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$create_params_do -> bindParam(':param4', $param4, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$create_params_do -> bindParam(':param5id', $param5id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$create_params_do -> bindParam(':param6id', $param6id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$create_params_do -> bindParam(':param7', $param7, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$create_params_do -> bindParam(':param8id', $param8id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$create_params_do -> bindParam(':param9', $param9, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$create_params_do -> bindParam(':param10', $param10, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$create_params_do -> bindParam(':param11', $param11, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$create_params_do -> bindParam(':param12', $param12, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$create_params_do -> bindParam(':param13', $param13, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$create_params_do -> bindParam(':param14', $param14, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$create_params_do -> bindParam(':param15', $param15, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$create_params_do -> bindParam(':param16', $param16, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$create_params_do -> bindParam(':param17', $param17, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$create_params_do -> bindParam(':param18', $param18, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$create_params_do -> bindParam(':param19', $param19, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$create_params_do -> bindParam(':param20', $param20, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$create_params_do -> bindParam(':param21', $param21, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$create_params_do->bindParam(':userid', $userid, PDO::PARAM_INT);

$create_params_do->execute() or die(print_r($create_params_do->errorInfo(), true));
//forgot to add when posting first sorry, i have that also.
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
$log->logError($e." - ".basename(__FILE__));
}


$err = "<div class=\"success\"><strong>"._("Congrats.")."</strong><br/>"._("Success.")."</div>";
}
```

Comment: Of course I don't know the point of the `cleanInput` function, but in general you *do not* need to clean the input when using `bindParam` as `bindParam` will do it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing

```
$create_params_do->execute();
```

at the end of params

Your query should be:

```
$create_params_query = "INSERT INTO `params`(`datenow`, `param1`, `param2`, `param3`, `param4`, `param5id`, `param6id`, `param7`, `param8id`, `param9`, `param10`, `param11`, `param12`, `param13`, `param14`, `param15`, `param16`, `param17`, `param18`, `param19`, `param20`, `param21`,`params_user_id`) VALUES(:datenow, :param1, :param2, :param3, :param4, :param5id, :param6id, :param7, :param8id, :param9, :param10, :param11, :param12, :param13, :param14, :param15, :param16, :param17, :param18, :param19, :param20, :param21, :userid)";
```

with `VALUES` not `VALUE`

Comment: i forgot to add while posting first, edited the post.so still need help but thanks anyway.

Comment: yes it is, just not included on post, works on other pages that i've created before, but this is not working i dont get the reason.

Comment: `$userid` is really session `:userid` with `:` ?

Comment: actually it can be the thing where the problem persists not sure about that, userid is the given id when user registers, the params_user_id is the another column in another table where i'd like to copy the userid for instance when user makes a comment exc.

Comment: `var_dump($_SESSION[':userid'])` to see if the userid exists

Comment: still no luck, even i've deleted all the user id things, still doesnt insert into database..

Comment: removed that, doesnt show the success message now, i think connection dies, but still dont know where the problem persists of.

Comment: Array ( [0] => 23000 [1] => 1048 [2] => Column 'datenow' cannot be null ) 

how come does it recognize it as a null , thank you by the way i know the error at least now .

Comment: If you datenow is a date in database you should use `NOW()` in mysql insert

Comment: it was datetime but changed to date, and made the datenow in the values NOW() as you said, but now getting Array ( [0] => HY093 )  error .

Comment: and you are inserting: `VALUES(NOW(),...` ? Do not assign `$datenow = NOW()`

Comment: oh at last done, thank you mihai, you are a saver, god bless you.

Comment: now its inserting into database as i wish but prints on screen after posting form : Array ( [0] => 00000 )  what does this mean by the way ?

Comment: it's outputting `$create_params_do->errorInfo()` array, you should use it otherway :)

Comment: oh okay no errors than thats cool thank you very much again mihai you are a saver :)

Answer (score 1):

To add to what Iorga side by default PDO is silent on errors so if you want to know what is happening, you will need to tell PDO to be noisy by setting setting PDO error_mode as show below. For your case VALUE or VALUES works (tested with MySQL 5.5). Catching the exception error will give you the really reason why it is not committing to the database.

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```